# Exchanging Data over the Network using indy component in Delphi xe5 between pc and android based system

Tags: android, delphi, send, indy

I used `IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(edit1.Text+crlf);` to send a text and, to receive, the code below is usd:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);

begin

  edit2.Text:=trim(AContext.Connection.IOHandler.readln(crlf));

  edit3.Text:='1';

end;
```

Both are correct in pc to pc connection. but when I send the data from pc to my android based phone, the procedure `TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute`runs and `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.readln(crlf)`  caused to terminate the process of the procedure and no data would be catched.

No ereror was detected and other parts work fine.

how can I receive data (string or numbers) in android based systems?

Comment: First, you don't need to explicitly specify `crlf`. Use `WriteLn(edit1.Text)` on the client side, it will send a `crlf` for you. Omit the terminator on the `ReadLn()` and it will handle both `lf` and `crlf` breaks for you. Second, there was an issue [recently discovered](http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/24989) on at least one Android tablet where the `Connection.IOHandler` property is nil in the `OnConnect` and `OnExecute` events, so check if that is also happening on your device. The cause of that has not been determined yet.

Comment: thank you Remy, now how can I  receive data (string or numbers) in android based systems? any Idea?

Comment: You did not answer my question - in the `OnExecute` event, is the `Connection.IOHandler` nil on your Android device?

Comment: No, I checked it, it is not nil.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you remove the direct access to the TEdit controls? `TIdTCPServer` is multithreaded, any access to the UI must be synchronized with the main thread, such as with `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TIdSync`, or else bad things can happen, including crashes. Have you tried wrapping the code in a `try/except` block, or using the `TIdTCPServer.OnException` event, to see if the crash is being caused by an uncaught exception, and if so what type it is?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the android version of my device is older than  what I installed in my PC (SDK). Try your program with older version. termination of your program is because of it.